# How to use `Searchkick.multi_search` along with `with_highlights`? undefined method `with_highlights'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

We're trying to optimize our search requests by making a single bulk search, so we're trying to use `Searchkick.multi_search`. However, it only returns `Searchkick::Query` with the results populated in a `results` attribute, as a regular `Array`.

Then, now if I try `results.with_highlights...` it fails with

```
undefined method `with_highlights' for #<Array:0x000055a82a7440f0>
```

Or if I try on the `search_query.with_highlights` it fails with

```
undefined method `with_highlights' for #<Searchkick::Query:0x00007f47c5d0cde8>
```

How can I get the highlights when using `multi_search`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer for Searchkick 4.6.1+**

Talked to Ankane from Searchkick here https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/pull/1518. He ended up releasing a new version with fixes to this then the original answer here is only valid up to  Searchkick version 4.6.0.

For 4.6.1+ just do:

```rb
  groups = Group.search(query, execute: false)
  users = User.search(query, execute: false)

  Searchkick.multi_search([groups, users])

  highlighted_groups_results = groups.with_highlights(...
  ...
```

**Original answer for 4.6.0-**

Got it!

After diving into the Searchkick codebase and checking the `Searchkick::Query` implementation, discovered that the `execute` method is what I need.

```
def execute
    @execute ||= begin
                     begin
                       response = execute_search
                       if retry_misspellings?(response)
                         prepare
                         response = execute_search
                       end
                     rescue => e # TODO rescue type
                       handle_error(e)
                     end
                     handle_response(response)
                   end
end
```

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/230ec8eb996ae93af4dc7686e02555d995ba1870/lib/searchkick/query.rb#L101

`handle_response(response)` is exactly what we need for making `with_highlights` work.

Then my final implementation ended up being something like the following:

```
groups = Group.search(query, execute: false)
users = User.search(query, execute: false)

Searchkick.multi_search([groups, users])

# execute here won't do any additional requests as it's already cached in an instance variable @execute
highlighted_groups_results = groups.execute.with_highlights(...
...
```